# Does $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})=\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H}^*$ in infinite dimensions?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, quantum-information

In quantum information contexts (where in most cases finite dimensions are considered) I have often seen the statement that the space of bounded linear operators $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ on a Hilbert space is (isomorphic to) the tensor product of the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with its dual $H^*$ (space of linear functionals). Is this only true in finite dimensions (where all operators are bounded anyway) or does it also apply to infinite dimensions? May I ask for a not too-technical answer without a lot of math jargon (I am a physicist, my apologies!)

Comment: You make this true, but then $\mathcal{H}$ should not be a Hilbert space. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_kernel_theorem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:** *Within $\infty$ it does **not** hold.*
When dealing with an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, then a norm on the tensor product $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H}^*$ is needed, followed by the corresponding norm completion. There is no unique choice for it, but you **never** get the full space of all bounded linear operators (which is a $C^*$-algebra).

The algebraic tensor product as it stands above is isomorphic to the algebra of finite-rank operators on $\mathcal H$, often denoted by
$\mathscr F(\mathcal H)$. This is the complement of those operators whose image is infinite-dimensional, e.g., the identity.

Three important choices (but far from all) of a norm are the

- *projective tensor product* 
  $\,\mathcal{H}\hat{\otimes}_\pi\mathcal{H}^*$
  which is isomorphic to the trace-class operators on $\mathcal H$,
- *Hilbert space tensor product* 
  $\,\mathcal{H}\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{H}^*$, isomorphic to the Hilbert-Schmidt operators on $\mathcal H$,
- *injective tensor product* 
  $\,\mathcal{H}\hat{\otimes}_\epsilon\mathcal{H}^*$
  being isomorphic to $\mathscr K(\mathcal H)$, the compact operators.

In a sense to be made precise, the first and the last one are the smallest ($\otimes_\pi$), and the largest
($\otimes_\epsilon$) reasonable completions, respectively.
You can find more on this SE site, e.g., [more technical info](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35191/)
or [here (regarding trace-class)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782698/how-can-we-prove-that-the-space-of-trace-class-operators-on-a-hilbert-space-h).

**Summa summarum**
$\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$ equals $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H}^*\,$ if and **only if** $\;\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask a (basic) question: with the “equality” $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})=H\otimes H^*$ one actually means isomorphism, right?

Comment: Yes, a "full isomorphism" is meant which also acknowledges the norm and all that. In the infinite-dim case it is crucial to take the norm into account, whereas in the finite-dim case you "may disregard them" coz there are all equivalent anyway.

Comment: @Hanno when dealing with general Banach spaces, the projective and injective tensor norms are the simplest examples. However, when dealing with Hilbert spaces $$ and $$, there is a natural cross norm turning the tensor product $\otimes $ into an inner product space (basically it's given by $\langle _1 \otimes y_1,x_2 \otimes y_2 \rangle = \langle x_1,x_2\rangle\langle y_1,y_2\rangle$). The tensor product of Hilbert spaces is usually understood to be the completion of this inner product space. It is Hilbert space isomorphic to the space of Hilbert–Schmidt operators $X^* \to Y$. [...]

Comment: [...] So when $X = \mathcal H^*$ and $Y = \mathcal H$, the Hilbert space tensor product is isomorphic (as a Hilbert space) to the space $L^2(\mathcal H)$ of all Hilbert–Schmidt operators on $\mathcal H$. This is a subspace of the space of all compact operators $K(\mathcal H)$, so in particular it is not all of $B(\mathcal H)$ whenever $\mathcal H$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you all so much. I actually have a follow-up question: is the failure to get the full space of all bounded linear operators somehow related to the well-known fact in quantum information/physics that in infinite dimensions there are states (i.e. linear , positive and normalized functionals on $\mathcal{B(H)}$ ) that are are not representable as a density operator?

Comment: @quantumorsch I cannot answer this from scratch, and for math.SE this is good news $\ddot\smile$
I ask U to spend a bit time to formulate a new question -- if it's not yet there -- which has the big advantage that the whole expert community may pay attention to it & enter into fruitful competition. And don't forget the tagging.

Comment: In the present Hilbert space context you @JossevanDobbendeBruyn mention another important norm completion, the Hilbert-Schmidt operators $\ell^2(\mathcal H)$. They form an ideal in $\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$, and lie between the projective and the injective tensor product. They are a particular instance of the Schatten ideals $\ell^p(\mathcal H)$ where $1\le p<\infty$.
And $\ell^1(\mathcal H)$ denotes the trace-class operators.
The $\ell^p$-notation refers to the summability properties of the sequences formed by the singular values which is a defining property of this operator ideals.

Answer (score 2):

Is $ H$ a Hilbert space, then  $H^* \otimes H \subset B ( H )$ is an isometric embedding in $B(H)$. It can be shown that with this identification the tensor product is the ideal $K(H)$ of all compact operators on $H$.

If $ \dim H < \infty$, then $K(H)=B(H)$. If $\dim H = \infty$, then $K(H)$ is a proper subset of $B(H)$.

Comment: Is the embedding really isometric? Let $H = \mathbb C^n$. The identity operator has norm $\sqrt n$ in the scalar product of $H^* \otimes H$ (which is the tensor product of the scalar products on $H^*$ and, respectively, $H$). On the other hand, the same identity operator has norm $1$ in $B(H)$. This is quite normal, since $H^* \otimes H$ has a natural structure of Hilbert space, while $B(H)$ is only a $C^*$-algebra (the norm is not given by a scalar product). So I disagree with your statement.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhat related: Using Hahn-Banach, for infinite dimensional $H$, you can make a state on $B(H)$ that vanishes on the compact operators but is 1 on the identity. That state does not come from a density operator.